# On tap, display value at a different location

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create a word game. I have a local json file where I'm retrieving data from. I'm able to retrieve the data and display it on the first row. What I'm trying to do is on tap of one block (on the first row), get the value and display it in order on the second row.

I'm able to retrieve the value but I can't display it on the second row. I tested this by printing the value in the console.

[image]

**Updated code:**

```
 body: new Container(
              child: new Center(
// Use future builder and DefaultAssetBundle to load the local JSON file
                child: new FutureBuilder(
                    future: DefaultAssetBundle
                        .of(context)
                        .loadString('data_repo/starwars_data.json'),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      var newData = JSON.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
                      List<Widget> listMyWidgets() {
                        List<Widget> list = new List();
                        for (var i = 0; i < newData.length; i++) {
                          var word = newData[i]['word']["letters"];
                          for (var n = 0; n < word.length; n++) {
                            list.add(new Text(word[n]['letter']));
                          }
                        }
                        return list;
                      }

                      List letters = [];
                      for (int i = 0; i < listMyWidgets().length; i++) {
                        var listMyWidgetsToString =
                            listMyWidgets()[i].toString();
                        var listWidgetToList =
                            listMyWidgetsToString.replaceAll('Text("', "");
                        var completeWordList =
                            listWidgetToList.replaceAll('")', "");
                        letters.add(completeWordList);
                      }
                      return new ListView.builder(
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return new Card(
                            child: new Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                              children: [
                                new Column(children: [
                                  new Image.asset(newData[0]['image'])
                                ]),
                                new GridView.count(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  crossAxisCount: listMyWidgets().length,
                                  children: new List.generate(
                                      listMyWidgets().length,
                                      (i) => new GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              final int wordLength =
                                                  5; //this is a ref to the lenght of the word so you do not keep adding tiles
                                              setState(() {
                                                (letters.length + 1) <=
                                                        wordLength * 2
                                                    ? letters.add(letters[i])
                                                    : null;
                                              });
                                            },
                                            child: new Card(
                                              elevation: 5.0,
                                              color: Colors.brown[500],
                                              child: new Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                child: new Center(
                                                    child:
                                                        new Text(letters[i])),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          )),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        itemCount: newData == null ? 0 : newData.length,
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to structure your data. In this example, I just add the pressed letters into the same array for the word and it will do the job.

Note that I keep a reference (which you may add to your JSON) which is the initial length of the word so it stops adding tiles when all letters are used.

[image]

**Also you need to have a `StatefulWidget` in order for this to work**

Probably there is a better a way to handle this but that is what I managed to do atm.

```
  class GridViewWords extends StatefulWidget {

      @override
      GridViewWordsState createState() {
        return new GridViewWordsState();
      }
    }

    class GridViewWordsState extends State<GridViewWords> {
      List letters = [
        "A",
        "M",
        "C",
        "I",
        "C"

      ];
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
          body: new GridView.count(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            crossAxisCount: 5,
            children: new List.generate(letters.length, (i)=>
            new GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
                  final int wordLength =5; //this is a ref to the lenght of the word so you do not keep adding tiles
                  setState((){
                  (letters.length+1)<=wordLength*2? letters.add(letters[i]):null;

                  });
                  },
                child: new Card(
                elevation: 5.0,
                color: Colors.brown[500],
                child: new Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: new Center(child: new Text(letters[i])),
                ),
              ),
            )),

          ),

        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. It doesn't seem to work on my end. I know the onTap works because when I tap on a block, I can print the letter. It doesn't display a new block like on yours. I'm not sure why that's happening.

Comment: I do not see you adding the clicked letter to the list anywhere. Your list of letters is being fed to the gridview and you need to use list.add(tappedLetter) inside your setState so that GridView keeps building itself from the same list as it grows

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is I took your code and added the gesture detector to the list. I'm not sure if there's a way to add code to the comment or if I should just update my initial post with the new code.

Comment: You need to initialize your letter list as a class member , look at my example I am declaring it as a global class field not local field inside the build method